# How to return value from my jquery function

Tags: javascript, c#

So I have a control (textbox) being created for each row in my grid view. (c#.net)

So for each of the text boxes, I want to find the current active element and return its id.

it kind of works, but I am having some issues.

I know `item.addEventListener` does not return a value.

Any ideas on how i can return the value after calling the `addListener()` function?

```js
var controls = {
    txt: null,
};
var selectedTextArea;
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("textboxnew");

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    controls = addListener(items[i], controls);
    alert(controls.txt);  ///GET ERROR HERE
}

function addListener(item, ctrls) {
    selectedTextArea = document.activeElement;
    ctrls.txt = selectedTextArea.name.toString();
    item.addEventListener("click", function () {
        selectedTextArea = document.activeElement;
        ctrls.txt = selectedTextArea.name.toString();
        alert(ctrls);
    });   
    return ctrls;   //VALUE NOT RETURNED ???
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like a jQuery to me anywhere! Can you post your HTML for reference here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jQuery.Callbacks()` to define a callback function that can be fired with parameters passed.

```js
var callbacks = jQuery.Callbacks();

function active(id) {
  alert(id)
}

callbacks.add(active);

$("input").on("click", function() {
  callbacks.fire(document.activeElement.id)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input id="1" autofocus tabindex="1">
<input id="2" tabindex="2">
<input id="3" tabindex="3">
```

Comment: So now with your code above, if i were to wrap that code in another function **$(function () { YOUR CODE } **  how can I get that "id" value??

Comment: What do you mean by "get that "id" value"? You can pass the value `id` within `active` function to another function `function active(id) { fn(id); }`.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to achieve you can alternatively use a `Promise` pattern to return a value from an asynchronous function call when the event occurs. Are you trying to await the click on each element then perform a task?